# firebase provided hosting-url which is not displaying my angular project's index page

Tags: angular, firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

For doing firebase hosting:-

1. created dist folder inside angular project by using "ng build --prod".
2. `firebase login`

3.

- Created project in console.firebase.google.com
- firebase init
- Choose firebase CLI features as hosting.
- same project name which i created earlier select here same.
- Enter public directory as dist.
- Say yes for spa.
- say no for overriding index.html

And then

4. `firebase deploy`

   it provides me url:- https://projectname.firebaseapp.com/
5. `firebase open`

But when i opened the hosting url then "welcome page confirming --Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" is displaying.

["image of Page displaying"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9gyq.png)

Please suggest where I am doing wrong? and how will my project's index page will start displaying.

Note :- I am not using firebase database so, i select only hosting while initializing.

Answer (score 3):

When you ran `firebase init` it asked you in which subfolder your public HTML content was stored. The default value for this is `public`. If you didn't explicitly type a different value, that's where your `index.html` will need to be.

Alternatively, open `firebase.json` in a text editor and change the value of the `public` property to point to the folder you're using. So something like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist"
  }
}
```

Also see the [documentation on Firebase Hosting configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#section-firebase-json).

Comment: In Angular 6+ apps using the Angular CLI this will be `"dist/app-name"`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should change `public` property and add your App name.

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/your_application_name",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems firebase won't attempt to traverse the directories within dist to fine a candidate to serve.  You must specify it explicitly